# Анимация перезапускается, хотя ещё не закончилась

Tags: java, android, анимация, imageview

У меня есть активность, в ней есть кнопка. При её нажатии создаётся ImageView, добавляется в layout и к картинке применяется анимация.
Проблема собственно в том, что при нажатии кнопки несколько раз анимация перезапускается на всех ImageView не закончившись

Вот код активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.nextInt(600);
        int y = rnd.nextInt(600);
        layout.addView(img, 50, 50);
        img.setX(x);
        img.setY(y);
        img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_anim));
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы для начала предложил приложить код

Comment: @Andrew, добавил код в вопрос

Comment: почему бы не отключать кнопку на период анимации, а потом включать обратно?

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: используйте `view.setEnabled(false)` или что-то типа такого, установите длительность анимации, и по ее окончанию включайте кнопку обратно

Comment: @Andrew, а как мне включить её обратно через какое-то время?

Comment: думаю несложно догадаться - `view.setEnabled(true)`

Comment: Да нет, это ясно, но как мне сделать это через заданное время в миллисекундах?

Comment: добавил ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
animator.setDuration(2000);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int value = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
    }
});
animator.start();
```

в слушателе переменная value будет расти от 0 до 100, и когда она будет равна 100, то вы сможете включить кнопку снова. Так же стоит добавить animator:

```
<animator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:valueFrom="20"
    android:valueTo="80"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:repeatCount="4"
    android:repeatMode= "restart"
    android:valueType="intType"></animator>
```

[Вот тут](https://en.proft.me/2017/02/5/android-animation-tutorial-examples/) есть интересный туториал по анимированию.